# How to save .wav file in MFC (use file dialog)

Tags: c++, mfc

```
void CRecordToMFCDlg::OnBnClickedButton7()
{
    /*TCHAR szFilter[] = _T("모든 파일(*.wav) || *.wav ||");
    CFileDialog dlg(FALSE, _T("all files"), _T("*.wav"),OFN_HIDEREADONLY| OFN_OVERWRITEPROMPT, szFilter);
    if (dlg.DoModal() == IDOK)
    {
        AfxMessageBox(dlg.GetPathName());

    }*/



    TCHAR szFilter[] = _T("wavefile(*.wav) || *.wav ||");
    CFileDialog dlgFile
    (false, _T("wavefile files"), _T("*.wav"), /*OFN_HIDEREADONLY |*/ OFN_OVERWRITEPROMPT, szFilter);

    if (IDOK == dlgFile.DoModal())
    {

        CString strPathName = dlgFile.GetPathName();


        CFile fScheduleWrite;
        if (!fScheduleWrite.Open
        (strPathName, CFile::modeCreate | CFile::modeWrite | CFile::typeBinary))
        {
            AfxMessageBox(_T("File Write Open Error"));
            return;
        }

    }

}
```

This code can save file but there isn't no data, I think that this code can't save my recording file cause this can't receive record data. How can I solve this problem? Does require related wave file header or format ?? Please answer me, if necessary upload header and code. Please

Answer (score 1):

The code you have shown obtains a target filename from the user and then creates the file, but it does not attempt to write any data to that file.

After `fScheduleWrite.Open()` is successful, you need to write your WAV data to the file as needed.

Nobody here can help you with that, as you did not indicate where your WAV data is coming from, or how it is being generated so you can access it for saving. There are many ways, many APIs, many libraries, that are able to produce WAV data.